# unnamed ints in bit field struct

Tags: c

Can someone explain me, why would I need these unnamed unsigned ints in this bit field struct?

```
struct box_props{
     unsigned int opaque      :       1;
     unsigned int fill_color  :       3;
     unsigned int             :       4;
     unsigned int show_border :       1;
     unsigned int border_color:       3;
     unsigned int border_style:       2;
     unsigned int             :       2;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that when you're trying to match some already-defined set of bits, which simply has holes (un-used bits) in those locations.

This is quite common with hardware registers and file formats, where space is often reserved for future use.

Note that you can never rely on the order in which the compiler assigns the bits to the bytes of the `struct`, so code using bitfields is rarely portable.

Answer (score 0):

These are there for padding reasons. If you do not want `fill_color` and `show_border` to share the same byte then you need those padding bits.